Why is "margin: 2rem auto" working fine for everything else but the form?
margin: 2rem auto doesn't work for the form element and it just sticks to the left of the page


.article {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  background: rgba(150, 75, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 3px dotted brown;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.form {
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
<main class="container">
  <article class="article">
    <h2>-</h2>
    <p>--</p>
  </article>
  <article class="article">
    <h2>-</h2>
    <p>-- </p>
  </article>
  <article class="article">
    <h2>-</h2>
    <p>--</p>
  </article>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <form class="form">
    <label for="Name">Yeehaw</label>
    <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="YeeHaw!" />
    <button>huh?</button>
  </form>
</footer>




You need to set width on the form.

Why should margin: 2rem auto; work on a form element when you're applying it to .article elements?
